# Json object cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, json, android-volley

In my code I need to show the normal text in a text view using JSON. I am using volley library to parse JSON. And my code is

```
public class PrincipalSpeechFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public PrincipalSpeechFragment(){}

private String urlJsonArry = "http://imaginetventures.net/sample/everwin_vidhyashram/webservice/rest/?module=speech&from=1-9-2014&to=30-9-2014";

private static String TAG = PrincipalSpeechFragment.class.getSimpleName();

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_PRINCIPAL_SPEECH ="Principal Speech";
private static final String TAG_SPEECH= "speech";
private static final String TAG_DESC = "desc";

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

private Button getPrincipalSpeech;

// Progress dialog
//private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private TextView txtResponse;

// temporary string to show the parsed response
private String jsonResponse;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal_speech, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getPrincipalSpeech = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.idForPrinciSpeech);

    txtResponse = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

    getPrincipalSpeech.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    makeJsonArrayRequest();
}

private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                // Parsing json array response
                // loop through each json object
                jsonResponse = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject speechobj = (JSONObject) response
                            .get(i);

                    /*String speech = speechobj.getString("speech");
                    String email = speech.getString("email");
                    JSONObject phone = speech
                            .getJSONObject("speech");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");*/

                    /*jsonResponse += "Speech: " + speech + "\n\n";
                    /*jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";*/
                    /*jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";*/

                }

                txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //hidepDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
}
```

When I click the button to get the result its just showing "org.json.JSON.EXCEPTION. and the value: -------- Json object cannot be converted to jsonarray"

I don't know what mistake I did. I am just getting those errors in toast. 
Kindly tell me.

Comment: what is value of Log.d(TAG, response.toString());?

Comment: A JSONObject can nest other JSONObjects and JSONArrays... look for the sentence which causes your exception and transform it calling attr.getJSONArray("attr");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String urlJsonArry = "http://imaginetventures.net/sample/everwin_vidhyashram/webservice/rest/?module=speech&from=1-9-2014&to=30-9-2014";
```

You're making a request to the url stated in your code, and if i paste it in a browser:

response:

```
{
    "Principal Speech": [
        {
            "speech": "Lorem (... et cetera)."
        }
    ]
}
```

And that is a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`. So you can make the `JSONArray` in your code a `JSONObject`, and then extract the `JSONArray` you probably want: `jsonObject.getJSONArray("Principal Speech");`

Edit: addition of code

```
private void makeJSONObjectRequest() { 

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(urlJsonArry, //Dont know where that came from, but JsonArrayRequest as classname will probably still work. Custom/your own class, I guess. As long as the type JSONArray is changed to JSONObject
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { //JSONObject instead of JSONArray
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {//JSONObject instead of JSONArray
            JSONArray speechArray = response.getJSONArray("Principal Speech"); //get the array from the JSONObject
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            // The rest is the same
            try {
                // Parsing json array response
                // loop through each json object
                jsonResponse = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject speechobj = (JSONObject) response
                            .get(i);

                    /*String speech = speechobj.getString("speech");
                    String email = speech.getString("email");
                    JSONObject phone = speech
                            .getJSONObject("speech");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");*/

                    /*jsonResponse += "Speech: " + speech + "\n\n";
                    /*jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";*/
                    /*jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";*/

                }

                txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //hidepDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

EDIT2: rewrite:

So JsonArrayObjectRequest is a little different from JsonObjectRequest

JSONArrayRequest

```
public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
}
```

JsonObjectRequest only has a constructor with 5 params you see in the `super` call (theres also one with 4 params, but still more than the 3 from jsonarrayrequest)

So we'll have to change a bit

```
private void makeJSONObjectRequest() { 
   Response.Listener<JSONObject> oklistener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { 
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            JSONArray speechArray = response.getJSONArray("Principal Speech"); 
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            // The rest is the same
            try {
                // Parsing json array response
                // loop through each json object
                jsonResponse = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < speechArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject speechobj = (JSONObject) speechArray.get(i);

                    /*String speech = speechobj.getString("speech");
                    String email = speech.getString("email");
                    JSONObject phone = speech
                            .getJSONObject("speech");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");*/

                    /*jsonResponse += "Speech: " + speech + "\n\n";
                    /*jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";*/
                    /*jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";*/

                }

                txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //hidepDialog();
        }
    };
    Response.ErrorListener errorlistener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //hidepDialog();
        }
    };
    //Above instantiated the listeners, to make it a little more understandable. Here the second param => null. That sets the method to GET
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(urlJsonArry, null, oklistener, errorlistener);

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: I need to print that speech content, how to do that. Can u pls edit my code.

Comment: @sanjayAD then i need source of jsonarrayRequest

Comment: Source??? "http://imaginetventures.net/sample/everwin_vidhyashram/webservice/rest/?module=speech&from=1-9-2014&to=30-9-2014";

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Ur answer was so helpful to me. But in JSONObject speechobj = (JSONObject) response.get(i); get is showing error. Don't know why. Also I wanna learn volley completely. Can u suggest me any tut.

Comment: @sanjayAD, sorry my bad. That line should be `JSONObject speechobj = (JSONObject)speechArray.get(i); (or speechArray.getJSONObject(i));`. Use the code from edit2

Answer (score 0):

Here in your response you got JSONObject so use below code.

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
```

and after

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Principal Speech");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

And use

```
   JsonArrayRequest  jr =new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, listener, errorListener) ;
```

Edit 2:

I check the source and it looks like below

```
 public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);

        }
```